# Re-using same grid datatables.net

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables-1.10

I have a bootstrapped template with datatables.net, I'd like to use the same datatables grid (same functionality/data) within the page, and a modal popup that gets fired from within the same page somewhere.

How would I be able to duplicate the exact same grid without duplicating my code?

Comment: Please provide a code example, i.e your markup and script. You want to show the same dataTable on both page and modal?

Comment: Sorry forgot about this post. You can initialize 2 grids with the same markup you usually can, like $('#grid1','#grid2').dataTable();